# Add questions to quiz on a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a `Many-To-Many relationship` between a `Quiz` table and a `Question` table. All I want to ask is how I get the logic down to be able to add a question to a quiz by the Quiz Id, so I can link multiple questions to one particular Quiz.

- Quiz entity side

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {
    CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(name = "quiz_content", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id"), 
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
)
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
```

- Question entity side

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questions")
private List<Quiz> quizList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is my Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public String addQuestionToQuiz(Quiz quiz, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        
       return "quiz/index";
    }
```

How can I implement the logic in the comments, because when I do, it throws an error like:

```
invalid property of bean class cannot get element with index 0 from set of size 0, accessed using property path.
```

Comment: Use a HashMap<Integer,List<Question>> where your key is the quiz Id and the value is a list of questions

Comment: Alright, thanks, would u suggest a good approach for this, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Set` instead of `List`. And you should not use cascading in this case. I added an implementation below with a test class where you can see how to add `Question` instances to `Quiz` instance.

Question class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questions")
    private Set<Quiz> quizList = new HashSet<>();
}
```

QuestionVM class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class QuestionVM {

    private long id;

    // TODO add remaining fields except for collections containing Quiz instances


    public QuestionVM(Question question) {
        this.id = question.getId();

        // TODO init remaining fields
    }
}
```

QuestionRepo

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface QuestionRepo extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> { }
```

Quiz class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Quiz {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "quiz_content",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    )
    private Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<>();

    public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        question.getQuizList().add(this);
        questions.add(question);
    }

    public void removeQuestion(Question question) {
        question.getQuizList().remove(this);
        questions.remove(question);
    }
}
```

QuizVM class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class QuizVM {

    private long id;
    private List<QuestionVM> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    // TODO add remaining fields

    public QuizVM(Quiz quiz) {
        this.id = quiz.getId();
        this.questions = quiz.getQuestions().stream().map(QuestionVM::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // TODO init remaining fields
    }
}
```

QuizRepo

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface QuizRepo extends JpaRepository<Quiz, Long> { }
```

QuizRepoTest

Update: Please note that OP was a little bit shifting during the process of answering this question, a process that lasted for days. Case went from using existing db instances to creating new db instances, then back to only using existing db instances. Hence tests below may not reflect the actual case.

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.misc;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJpaTest
public class QuizRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    QuizRepo quizRepo;

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepo questionRepo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        var quizInDb = new Quiz();
        var question1InDb = questionRepo.save(new Question());
        var question2InDb = questionRepo.save(new Question());

        quizInDb.addQuestion(question1InDb);
        quizInDb.addQuestion(question2InDb);

        quizInDb = quizRepo.save(quizInDb);

        // verify that Quiz instance has 2 questions
        var quiz = testEntityManager.find(Quiz.class, quizInDb.getId());
        assertThat(quiz.getQuestions().size()).isEqualTo(2);

        // verify that question #1 has 1 Quiz instance
        var question1 = testEntityManager.find(Question.class, question1InDb.getId());
        assertThat(question1.getQuizList().size()).isEqualTo(1);

        // remove question #1 from Quiz instance
        quizInDb = quizRepo.getOne(quiz.getId());
        question1InDb = questionRepo.getOne(question1.getId());
        quizInDb.removeQuestion(question1InDb);
        quizRepo.save(quizInDb);

        // verify that Quiz instance has 1 question
        quiz = testEntityManager.find(Quiz.class, quiz.getId());
        assertThat(quiz.getQuestions().size()).isEqualTo(1);

        // verify that question #1 has 0 Quiz instances
        question1 = testEntityManager.find(Question.class, question1InDb.getId());
        assertThat(question1.getQuizList().size()).isEqualTo(0);

        questionRepo.delete(question1InDb);

        // verify that question #1 is deleted from db
        assertThat(testEntityManager.find(Question.class, question1InDb.getId())).isNull();

        quizInDb = quizRepo.getOne(quiz.getId());
        question2InDb = quizInDb.getQuestions().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
        question2InDb.setComment("test");
        quizRepo.save(quizInDb);

        var question2 = testEntityManager.find(Question.class, question2InDb.getId());
        assertThat(question2.getComment()).isEqualTo("test");
    }
}
```

QuizService class (please note question was about adding Question instances to Quiz instance, hence logic for removing Question instances is not added).

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class QuizService {

    private final QuizRepo quizRepo;
    private final QuestionRepo questionRepo;

    public void saveQuiz(QuizVM quiz) {

        var quizInDb = quizRepo.getOne(quiz.getId());

        quiz.getQuestions().stream()
                .filter(questionVM ->
                        quizInDb.getQuestions().stream()
                                .noneMatch(questionInDb -> questionInDb.getId() == questionVM.getId()))
                .forEach(questionVM -> quizInDb.addQuestion(questionRepo.getOne(questionVM.getId())));
        
        quizRepo.save(quizInDb);
    }
}
```

Controller method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public String addQuestionToQuiz(QuizVM quiz, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    quizService.saveQuiz(quiz);
    return "redirect:/quiz/index";
}
```

Comment: @Mavro: Inject the service instead of the repository. First test that your code hits the controller with my controller method code in my answer. BR

Comment: Yes, I have the service. Let me explain a bit: I have the Thymeleaf Option in my frontend, where I have a quizID coming from the database and a form-row that has a questionID coming from the database. So I can link a question to that particular Quiz. Right now I don't have any Id in my database and in the save method from Service, I get a nullPointerException again, this time on the first line of code, which is: Quiz quizDb = quiz.getId() > 0 ? quizRepository.getOne - etc. I guess because I don't have any Id selected, right? But shouldn't that be automatically generated?

Comment: I don't seem to have the necessary reputation in order for me to be able to chat there... I need at least 20. But, the thing is: after that first line in the quizService, I need to do something like: quizdb.setId(quiz.getId())? That's what u meant by "//TODO copy updated fields from QuizVm instance to quizDb? And the same for questions? like after the stream, I have to say something like: currentQuestion.setId, setSubject and everything I have in my Question class? Its kinda hard to follow this :)) But anyway, i just wanna say thanks a lot for your answers until now, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mavro: QuizVM#id should be populated with quiz id from db. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, but right now I don;t have any Quizzez in my DB, so therefore there's no ID in my DB for Quiz. That's why, I guess, it says Null. But shouldn't that be populated with an id, because I have auto_increment and @GeneratedValue in my db/code? Right now, there's no Quiz ID that can link my Question to it...But idk why it doesn't auto generate...

Comment: @Mavro: Just saw that I was missing this in my service class: `quizRepo.save(quizInDb);` at the very end. Please update your code from my answer. The service should create a new Quiz instance when QuizVM#id == 0. Please tell me which line of code is failing.

Comment: No problem, I already had  ```quizRepo.save``` at the end, so that's not the problem. When I create a breakpoint, I see that on that first line from ```quizService```, which is: Quiz quizInDb = quiz.getId()) > 0 ? quizRepository.getOne(quiz.getId()) : new Quiz(), my quiz comes with id = null. But shouldn't that : new Quiz() code there generate a quiz with a generated Id?

Comment: @Mavro: I don't think I understand the problem here. What do you need the id for before saving the Quiz instance? Just tested saving a new Quiz instance like this, and it is working: `var quizInDb = quizRepo.save(new Quiz());`

Comment: @Mavro: Updated my test for what I think is your case. Updated service code accordingly. Yes, please go ahead with your question. BR

Comment: So, right now I am back where I started, which means I enter my Question Id in the frontend form and it creates a Quiz. Shouldn't that reflect on the ```quiz_content``` table in my DB which has the ```quiz_id``` and my ```question_id```? So I can see what Quiz is linked to which Question and vice versa?  And can you please update your answer at that comment which says //Copy update values from QuizVm instance to quizInDb? I have done something there but I don't know if I got that right.

Comment: @Mavro: The original case in your question is that you want to link Question instances that exists in db to an Quiz instance that exists in db. Then you are saying that there is no Quiz instance in db. I hope you understand that I'm kind of confused now.

Comment: Well, yes, but let's say this is a new project. I can't have a Quiz instance already in my DB, so the first one needs to be generated. Then, I can choose to select the same Quiz Id that was first generated and link the next, let's say, 20 questions to that Quiz. But if I don't want to, I want to be able to generate another Quiz Id, so I can have multiple ones, not just one Quiz. Yes, I know you are confused, because I am, too, so my explanation isn't quite good. I know what I am trying to achieve, but I can't quite explain it...Sorry for that...

Comment: @Mavro: My test is showing that the db-layer supports  both new Quiz instances and new Question instances, so I guess that you have to investigate that test a little bit further in order to get finished. We are well out of bounds of the original question, and after spending hours on this, I think you should ask a new question containing your Thymeleaf code. You should consider both upvoting my answer and accept it, and I'll probably talk to you in your next question. BR

Comment: Hey, Roar, I just want to let you know that I have completed my task. Your advice and code was helpful, although I had to make some changes to make it work. But in the end, I got what I wanted. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Mavro: Good to hear that things are working now. Your case grew a little bit, but I hope it was nothing wrong in my test (that is running) for your original question. Please feel free to present your final result in a separate answer, and I will upvote that answer if it may be beneficial for others in the future. BR

Answer (score 0):

This is a bidirectional relationship so you need to handle add or remove operations with custom methods to avoid any unpredictable errors. You should add a custom `addQuestion()` method to the owing side which is the `Quiz` entity.

```
@Entity
public class Quiz {
    //...
    public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        questions.add(question);
        question.getQuizList().add(this);
    }
    //...
}
```

Then you can add a question to a quiz:

```
Question question = new Question();
questionRepository.save(question);

Quiz quiz = quizRepository.findById(quizId).get();
quiz.addQuestion(question);
quizRepository.save(quiz);
```

PS: I recommend you to use `Set` instead of `List` on a `@ManyToMany` relationship for a better performance.

Comment: Well, I already have these custom methods, the only thing I will change there is changing my code to use a Set instead of List . The problem I had was getting the logic down to add many questions to one particular Quiz Id, right now is adding a Question to a Quiz and so on, creating a single Quiz with only one Question. I will see what I can do with your info, thanks!

Comment: Already did, but since I have under 15 reputation, the vote change will not reflect, although the vote was recorded. ^_^ Btw, now I get some error @InvalidPropertyException ,I guess  since elements from the Set interface cannot be accesed by index. Should I make another method to return a List that wraps my Set? Thx.

Comment: This should be the syntax : @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questions")
 private Set<Quiz> quizList = new HashSet<>(); I don't think you need an additional method or sth. Probably the error is related to a different issue.

Comment: Yep, that's the syntax. Yeah, maybe it is another problem, will try to figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With some help from fellow contributers, I have been able to get the problem solved.
I will post my code here, maybe it will be beneficial for someone trying the same thing.

- QuizService:

```
 @Override
    public void save(QuizVM quiz) {

        Quiz quizDb = !isNull(quiz.getId()) && quiz.getId() > 0 ? quizRepository.getOne(quiz.getId()) : new Quiz();

        Set<Question> questionsToSave = quiz.getQuestions()
                .stream()
                .filter(f -> !isNull(f.getId()))
                .filter(g -> questionRepository.existsById(g.getId()))
                .map(Question::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        quizDb.setQuestions(questionsToSave);

        quizRepository.save(quizDb);
    }
```

I also want to point out that in order for this to work, I had to create a constructor in my `Question` class that takes the `QuestionVM` as an argument, like so:

```
public Question(QuestionVM questionVM){
        this.id = questionVM.getId();
    }
```

Finally, the `Controller` code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public String addQuestionToQuiz(QuizVM quiz, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        quizService.save(quiz);

        List<Quiz> quizList = quizService.findAll();

        return "redirect:/quiz/index";
    }
```

Comment: If you follow my code that is use long instead of Long for id field, my service implementation should work. I don't understand your QuizService implementation, 
you are creating new instances of `Question` when they already exists in db, and you are not saving new questions. When adding `Question` instances to `Quiz` instance, you are not using the `addQuestion` method, hence there will be no many-to-many from question to quiz. When the above is fixed, fix `Question` constructor, it is bad to tamper with id generated by db. I saw the question was downvoted, that was not me.

Comment: To your controller method: You are correctly doing a redirect-after-post, but doing the following, is meaningless: `model.addAttribute("quizList", quizList);`

Comment: Yep, I have modified the ```Controller``` to get rid of that ```model.addAttribute``` thing.

Comment: And if your case is just to add existing questions to a Quiz instance, you can get rid of `QuestionVM` as well and just have a collecion of question id in `QuizVM`, only if you are not using QuestionVM elsewhere. BR

Comment: Yeah, that's my case, to add existing questions to a ```Quiz```, because I have a separate``` Controller``` and logic for creating a ```Question```. I'll keep it this way, tho, for now. Thanks!

Comment: OK, updated my answer with a new version of `QuizService` for this scenario. BR

Comment: You should update this answer with some other code, or remove it in order to avoid down-votes (which in turn decreases to creds).